# Rabbitmq server crash randomly occur and I don't know why

Tags: crash, rabbitmq, crash-reports

I want to know the cause of Rabbitmq crash which randomly occur. can you let me know what kind of causes could be considered?

Also my team should manually restart the rabbitmq when crash happens, so I want to know if there is a way to restart rabbitmq server automatically.

Here is the error report when rabbitmq crash occur:

```
=WARNING REPORT==== 6-Dec-2017::07:56:43 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.4387.0> (000000:23070 -> 00000:5672, vhost: '/', user: '00000'):
client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
```

Also this is part of sasl.gsd fild :

```
=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 7-Dec-2017::10:03:15 ===
     Supervisor: {local,sockjs_session_sup}
     Context:    child_terminated
     Reason:     {function_clause,
                     [{gen_server,cast,
                          [{},sockjs_closed],
                          [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,218}]},
                      {rabbit_ws_sockjs,service_stomp,3,
                          [{file,"src/rabbit_ws_sockjs.erl"},{line,150}]},
                      {sockjs_session,emit,2,
                          [{file,"src/sockjs_session.erl"},{line,173}]},
                      {sockjs_session,terminate,2,
                          [{file,"src/sockjs_session.erl"},{line,311}]},
                      {gen_server,try_terminate,3,
                          [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,629}]},
                      {gen_server,terminate,7,
                          [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,795}]},
                      {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                          [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}
     Offender:   [{pid,<0.20883.1160>},
                  {id,undefined},
                  {mfargs,
                      {sockjs_session,start_link,
                          ["pd4tvvi0",
                           {service,"/stomp",
                               #Fun<rabbit_ws_sockjs.1.47892404>,{},
                               "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/sockjs/1.0.3/sockjs.min.js",
                               false,true,5000,25000,131072,
                               #Fun<rabbit_ws_sockjs.0.47892404>,undefined},
                           [{peername,{{172,31,6,213},9910}},
                            {sockname,{{172,31,5,49},15674}},
                            {path,"/stomp/744/pd4tvvi0/htmlfile"},
                            {headers,[]},
                            {socket,#Port<0.12491352>}]]}},
                  {restart_type,transient},
                  {shutdown,5000},
                  {child_type,worker}]


=CRASH REPORT==== 7-Dec-2017::10:03:20 ===
  crasher:
    initial call: sockjs_session:init/1
    pid: <0.25851.1160>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {function_clause,
                        [{gen_server,cast,
                             [{},sockjs_closed],
                             [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,218}]},
                         {rabbit_ws_sockjs,service_stomp,3,
                             [{file,"src/rabbit_ws_sockjs.erl"},{line,150}]},
                         {sockjs_session,emit,2,
                             [{file,"src/sockjs_session.erl"},{line,173}]},
                         {sockjs_session,terminate,2,
                             [{file,"src/sockjs_session.erl"},{line,311}]},
                         {gen_server,try_terminate,3,
                             [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,629}]},
                         {gen_server,terminate,7,
                             [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,795}]},
                         {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                             [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}
      in function  gen_server:terminate/7 (gen_server.erl, line 800)
    ancestors: [sockjs_session_sup,<0.177.0>]
    messages: []
    links: [<0.178.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: true
    status: running
    heap_size: 987
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 175
  neighbours:
```

Please check out the error report I posted above and let me know the causes of rabbitmq crash and the way to automatically restart rabbitmq server.

Thanks!!